# How to generate email from byte array and add attachment to it

Tags: asp.net, .net, email, email-attachments, email-client

I am working on a asp.net application. It has following method :

```
private bool SaveDocumentFile(string FilePath, string FileName, byte[] Data)
        {
            BinaryWriter Writer = null;
            string Name = "";
            try
            {    
                Name = FilePath + "\\" + FileName;

                // Create a new stream to write to the file
                Writer = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite(Name));

                // Writer raw data                
                Writer.Write(Data);
                Writer.Flush();
                Writer.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error(ex.Message + " SaveDocumentFile Exception");
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
```

FileName parameter can be word,PDF or email format.

If file name contains .msg extension,byte array will have details such as from, to, email subject, email body etc. Function will save the file with .msg exension. If I open saved file in outlook it will have from,to,subject and body field populated.

Now I want to add a condition so the whenever file format is .msg, SaveDocumentFile function should add an attachment from a folder stored on common location to a .msg file.

Is this achievable? If yes how? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What should "SaveDocumentFile" function do? Add an attachment to what?

Comment: It should add attachment to a .msg file. I update my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use [MSG.NET](http://www.independentsoft.com/msg/index.html) (not free). See the [add attachement tutorial](http://www.independentsoft.com/msg/tutorial/addattachment.html).

```
using Independentsoft.Msg;

Message message = new Message("c:\\temp\\message.msg");
Attachment attachment = new Attachment("c:\\temp\\test.pdf");
message.Attachments.Add(attachment);
message.Save("c:\\temp\\message.msg", true);
```